# Program Safety Planes for Universal Robotics (UR-10) in UR script language

Tags: robotics

My university just purchased a UR-10 for our mechanical engineering department and I'm currently working on it as a summer project.

I was learning how to use the scripting language, reading through the documentation, but I could not find anywhere the ability to programmatically define safety planes.

As of right now, we want to setup safety planes using a depth camera we have, but I can't find any documentation on the subject.

I'm just curious to know if there is a command that takes a positional argument that would let me set up a safety plane in a room a distance away from the robot arm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to programmatically create safety planes for the UR-10. You have to just create joint limits for certain motions you don't want the arm to move in.